# Glide v4.4 disable memory cache and disk cache failure

Tags: android, android-glide

The image file is downloaded from the server and always save to the same file name.

So in earlier version of glide, i have been tested with

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadPath));
GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(uri)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .into(mDownloadImageView);
```

It seems work for the file with the same name when its image changes. The offical document [Glide Caching](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) mentioned like above.

But now in Glide 4.4.0, i used this code again and it is not working. I need to add the signature like below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadPath));
GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(uri)
        .signature(new ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .into(mDownloadImageView);
```

After adding the signature key, then it works.

Does anyone met the same scenario? DiskcacheStrategy None and skip memory cache true as no effect at all to me.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `RequestOptions` now.

```
 Glide.with(this).load(imageResource)
        .apply(RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_profile_image)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .dontAnimate())
        .into(profileImageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have the same problem.
I have to use signature with diskCacheStrategy() set to NONE and skipMemoryCache() set to true if I want to refresh image every time.

Another problem is that if I use diskCacheStrategy() set to ALL with some signature (in order to force cache refresh on some occasions) - it is not working. Signature is changing every time but Glide always loads image from cache and doesn't want to refresh it.

It was working great on Glide v3 and stopped working correctly after upgrading to v4.